# How to pin the menu to the upper part of the screen?

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to creat a side menue.
and im not sure what is the best way to do this.
my question is how to pin the menu to the upper part of the screen?
thank you :)

[image: printscreen]

this is the HTML

```
<!--menu-->

<div class="menu">
<div class="option" align="center">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">דף הבית</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">צור קשר</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">בלוג</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">מי את גברת?</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<!--endmenue-->
```

the CSS

```
div.menu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    right: 0;


}

div.option{
    padding-top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;

}

div.option a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.option ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: alef;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    line-height: 400%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your body margin set to 0?

Comment: It IS pinned by using `position: fixed` what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
div.menu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    right: 0;
    top: 0; // added this
}
```

I added `top:0` which attaches the element to the top of it's parent

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS I would add 
    *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
This will help with pesky unwanted margin and padding

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this?

```
div.menu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    right: 0;
}

div li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

div.option a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.option ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: alef;
    color: white;
    line-height: 200%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

See here [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqLmmk95/)